# Change Service Account in CDAP Preview mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

In a Cloud Data Fusion deployment, I have a requirement to enable preview mode to be used by data engineers. But have a security requirement to not do that through Google Default Service account.
Is there a was to change the service account used in preview mode? or any workarounds for that?

Thanks
Eman

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to customize the service account used for preview. It runs with GCP service account of the form service-@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

Preview mode is typically used for testing the pipeline structure. As a workaround you can probably try DEVELOPER edition where pipelines can be tested with low cost compared to ENTERPRISE edition.

Thanks,

Sagar